# Tabela para gravar histórico registro (Melhor forma)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estou com uma duvida qual seria a melhor forma de criar um tabela para que cada ação de um registro seja salvo criando assim um histórico do mesmo. Tenho a seguinte tabela, mas não sei se é a melhor.

```
create table sispro_historico_processo (
    id_historico_processo int(10) UNSIGNED not null primary key auto_increment,
    cd_titular int(10) not null,
    cd_processo int(10) not null,
    in_situacao_processo int(2) not null,
    dh_alteracao_registro datetime default null
);
```

A ideia é que para cada ação que o registro sofrer cria-se um novo registro nessa tabela alterando praticamente a situação do precesso, quem alterou e a data/hora.

obrigado.

Comment: Acredito que a melhor forma é criar uma cópia da tabela original, acrescentando os campos para armazenar a data de alteração, quem alterou e o id do registro alterado.

Comment: ta resolvido a questão ?

Comment: Talvez você precise criar uma `procedure` em seu banco de dados.

Answer (score 4):

Como o William mencionou eu faço uma "cópia" da tabela original adicionando os demais campos que me informam sobre o que aconteceu com o que foi registrado tipo assim:

```
    CREATE TABLE `log_tab_fornecedor` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, -- PK do log
  `user_nome` varchar(30) NOT NULL,     -- nome do usuario que fez a alteraçao
  `data_hora` datetime NOT NULL,        -- DATA/HORA DA ALTERAÇÃO
  `host` varchar(45) NOT NULL,          -- MAQUINA QUE ALTEROU
  `operacao` varchar(2) NOT NULL,       -- OPERACAO I=INSERT, D=DELETE, U=UPDATE
  `for_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'pk',   -- ATRIBUTO DA TABELA ORIGINAL
  `for_nome` varchar(45) NOT NULL COMMENT 'nome',   -- ATRIBUTO DA TABELA ORIGINAL
  `for_cnpj` varchar(18) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'cnpj',-- ATRIBUTO DA TABELA ORIGINAL
  `for_tipo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'tipo',-- ATRIBUTO DA TABELA ORIGINAL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

e a tab_fornecedor seria assim:

```
    CREATE TABLE `tab_fornecedor` (
  `for_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'pk',
  `for_nome` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'nome',
  `for_cnpj` varchar(18) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'cnpj',
  `for_tipo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'tipo',
  `for_cpf` varchar(14) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'CPF',
  `for_tipo_pes` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`for_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=502 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Fornecedores';
```

Inclusive eu separo a as tabelas que são log's tudo em outra database parar ficar mais organizado.

Fazendo uma consulta no log:

```
    mysql> select * from log_tab_fornecedor where for_id=305;
+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------+----------+--------+-----------------------+----------+----------+
| id | user_nome | data_hora           | host          | operacao | for_id | for_nome              | for_cnpj | for_tipo |
+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------+----------+--------+-----------------------+----------+----------+
| 14 | root      | 2014-07-23 09:25:28 | 192.168.1.100 | I        |    305 | MISTERIO DA FAZENDA   |          |        3 |
| 14 | root      | 2014-07-23 09:24:28 | 192.168.1.100 | U        |    305 | MINISTERIO DA FAZENDA |          |        3 |
| 15 | root      | 2014-07-23 09:25:03 | 192.168.1.100 | U        |    305 | MINISTÉRIO DA FAZENDA | NULL     |        3 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------+----------+--------+-----------------------+----------+----------+
```

**Outro detalhe importante** para não se estressar fazendo esses insert's na tabela de log, fazer as triggers para que esse serviço seja automátizado:

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`127.0.0.1` TRIGGER `local`.`tg_tab_fornecedor_after_u`
AFTER UPDATE ON `local`.`tab_fornecedor`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION /*DECLARAR EXECEÇÃO*/ 
    RESIGNAL SQLSTATE '21S01' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'TRIGGER tg_tab_fornecedor_after_u';/*RETORNA O NOME DA TRIGGER EM CASO DE ERRO*/
    /*LOG - INSERIR NOVO REGISTRO DE LOG */
    set @id = (select ifnull(max(id)+1,1) from local_log.log_tab_fornecedor);
    insert into local_log.log_tab_fornecedor
        values(         
            @id,
            substring_index(session_user(),'@',1),
            now(),
            substring_index(session_user(),'@',-1),
            'U',
            NEW.`for_id`,
            NEW.`for_nome`,
            NEW.`for_cnpj`,
            NEW.`for_tipo`                              
        );
END

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`127.0.0.1` TRIGGER `local`.`tg_tab_fornecedor_after_i`
AFTER DELETE ON `local`.`tab_fornecedor`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION /*DECLARAR EXECEÇÃO*/ 
    RESIGNAL SQLSTATE '21S01' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'TRIGGER tg_tab_fornecedor_after_i';/*RETORNA O NOME DA TRIGGER EM CASO DE ERRO*/
    /*LOG - INSERIR NOVO REGISTRO DE LOG */
    set @id = (select ifnull(max(id)+1,1) from local_log.log_tab_fornecedor);
    insert into local_log.log_tab_fornecedor
        values(         
            @id,
            substring_index(session_user(),'@',1),
            now(),
            substring_index(session_user(),'@',-1),
            'D',
            OLD.`for_id`,
            OLD.`for_nome`,
            OLD.`for_cnpj`,
            OLD.`for_tipo`      
        );
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você esteja procurando algo parecido com o [Hibernate Envers](http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/) do Java.

Para PHP, você pode optar pelo uso do [Propel](http://propelorm.org/), que possui suporte a [versionamento dos registros](http://propelorm.org/Propel/behaviors/versionable.html).

> Once enabled on a table, the versionable behavior stores a copy of the
>   ActiveRecord object in a separate table each time it is saved. This
>   allows to keep track of the changes made on an object, whether to
>   review modifications, or revert to a previous state.

Em tradução livre:

> Uma vez habilitado em uma tabela, o comportamento de versionamento
>   guarda uma cópia de cada objeto ActiveRecord em uma tabela separada
>   cada que é salvo. Isto permite monitorar as mudanças em um objeto,
>   avaliar as modificações ou reverter para um estado anterior

[Este link](http://propelorm.org/blog/2010/12/22/propel-1-6-gets-versionable-behavior-with-a-twist.html) explica com mais detalhes como usá-lo.