# Gravar Histórico (Log de Modificações) PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

boa noite!

Gostaria de saber como criar um histórico, uma página onde eu posso visualizar tudo o que foi modificado em uma página, por exemplo:

Possuo uma página de Cadastro de Telefone Corporativo, onde todos possuem acesso, logo eu gostaria de poder ter um registro de quem fez a última alteração em alguns campos como "Modelo do Telefone, quem fez a alteração e a data, etc...".

É basicamente o que está aqui, porém eu não consegui entender como farei isso...

[Tabela para gravar histórico registro (Melhor forma)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64699/tabela-para-gravar-hist%C3%B3rico-registro-melhor-forma)

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português :D Editei sua pergunta para deixá-la mais direta. Recomendo visitar o [tour] para conhecer um pouco mais como o Stack Overflow funciona.

Comment: O que você não entendeu exatamente?